LangchainJS vectorRetriever returns generic results, as if my data is not being read
I'm using LangChain JS (with a Pinecone vector store) to query data that has been stored. The following code seems to work (syntax-wise), but the respons is generic, it feels as if it's talking to ChatGPT, and not my own data in the vector store.
Am I missing something?
const pinecone = new Pinecone();
const pineconeIndex = pinecone.Index(process.env.PINECONE_INDEX!);

const vectorStore = await PineconeStore.fromExistingIndex(
  new OpenAIEmbeddings(),
  { pineconeIndex },
);

const vectorStoreRetriever = vectorStore.asRetriever();

// Initialize OpenAI Chat model
const model = new ChatOpenAI({
  openAIApiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY, // Your OpenAI API key
  model: 'gpt-4o-mini',
  temperature: 0,
});

const SYSTEM_TEMPLATE = `Use the following pieces of context to answer the question at the end.
If you don't know the answer, just say that you don't know, don't try to make up an answer.
----------------
{context}`;

const prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.fromMessages([
  ['system', SYSTEM_TEMPLATE],
  ['human', '{question}'],
]);

const chain = RunnableSequence.from([
  {
    context: vectorStoreRetriever.pipe(formatDocumentsAsString),
    question: new RunnablePassthrough(),
  },
  prompt,
  model,
  new StringOutputParser(),
]);

const answer = await chain.invoke(
  'Tell me a bit about the data you have stored in your vectors',
);

